# How to send SMS from ASP.NET application by way of a GSM modem

Tags: asp.net, sms, gsm

If GSM modem has to be used to send SMS, then what are the hardware and software requirements to setup the entire thing?

Answer (score 5):

You need a GSM modem (mobile handset or similar) attached to the server.

Typically, SMS can be sent by using AT commands on the serial interface of the GSM hardware.

See [this tutorial](http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

[This library](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm) offers a simple interface to send SMSs though a Gsm Modem