# Is it possible Connecting and sending message through GSM modem using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gsm

I ve developed a c# winforms application for sending sms by using this article of [Sending sms using GSM](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SMS.aspx)  It works pretty well... Now i want to send sms using GSM communication (ie) a mobile phone connected to PC and i have detect it and send sms using it in asp.net.....

Is it possible Connecting and sending message through GSM modem using asp.net?

Comment: Is the phone connected to the ASP.NET apps erver or the client PC.. If the earlier, then I see no problems other that trust issues in code executing on the server.

Comment: @preet i dont want to host it in a server.. Just a client mavhine....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can! The only point is that, as ASP.NET is a server side programming, the GSM modem will have to be connected to the server running the app. Even, your already developed code can be reused. Put that code as an assembly with public interface to get the functionalities. Include it in the ASP.NET app and you can send SMS.

Comment: There is another link similar to taha of yours on Stackoverflow. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406393/how-to-send-sms-from-asp-net-application-by-way-of-a-gsm-modem You can disclose how your current app is organise. I feel, you just need to reuse the same.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference if your app is a regular console/winforms app or whether it's an ASP.NET app.

You would just want to be a bit more security-conscious if anyone on the internet is able to connect to your website and send messages...

Comment: @codekka i will not host this on a server it will be just in a client machine... Any helpful link which does this for me...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could create a Windows service that contains the logic for accessing the GSM modem and sending SMS messages. This service can then be access from your ASP.NET web  application.

There are lots of articles out there on running a WCF service as a Windows service, here's one on MSDN, [Hosting and Consuming WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx).

But on second thought, setting up a service may be overkill here. You could use your library from within your app just as fine.

Comment: Updated my answer ... but Google is the place to look for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as mentioned by Kangkan in his answer. You will need to **connect your modem to the server which is less feasible and very much less recommended** to do so. The best option you can have is to **subscribe to a third-party SMS gateway** and send SMS through their HTTP apis. There are many such providers available that provide this kindaa service. Just google them and you'll find the one that best suits your needs.

Comment: @ya definitely try that... But i need a free sms api.. Is there one?... If so, can i expect them to work all the time?

Comment: Try Way2Sms. I havent checked it but there's some code here, http://codeglobe.blogspot.com/2010/03/way2sms-php.html